# How do we interact with a list referenced through a different list?

Tags: python, list

Lets say I have a list that references another list, as follows:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [list1[0], list1[1], list1[2]]
```

I wish to interact with list1 through list2, as follows:

```
list2[1] = 'a'
print(list1[1])
```

and that result should be 'a'.
Is this possible? Help me python geniuses

Comment: Assignments don't work that way. Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Is List2 always referencing that single List1 or can it be referencing multiple lists?

Comment: `list1[0]` gets the object that is in the first position of the list. There is no memory of where that object happend to come from.

Comment: You could simply have `List2 = List1` - that is, they both reference the same list. If your requirements are different than that, can you give an explanation? Do you want to limit the size or maybe mix up index (e.g., List2[3] references List1[0])?

Comment: You have a typo - `list[1]` should result in a compilation error

Answer (score 1):

First, I think there is a typo in your example, I expect it should be:

```
List1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
List2 = [List1[0], List1[1], List1[2]]
```

Anyway, when you do `List1[1]`, this slices/subsets the second element, and then any link to `List1` is lost.

However, if you were to do:

```
List3 = [List1, List2]
List3[0][1] = 'a'
```

As what is stored in List3[0] is a reference to List1, then this would effectively modify List1:

```
>>> List3
[[1, 'a', 3, 4, 5], ['b', 'a', 3]]
>>> List1
[1, 'a', 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = list1
list2[1]= "a"
```

Comment: But `list2[4] = "a"` would work when OP's example shows that list2 has 3 elements. I think OP needs to give use more requirements.